# Npm package Vue3 UI library don't run in Nuxt

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a UI library with Vue3 Composition API components. It works fine in other Vue projects but there is a problem in Nuxt 2.6 project.

My library has component Badge

```
// components/badge.vue

<template>
  <div :class="classes">{{ label }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'badge',

  props: {
      label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    highlighted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    props = reactive(props);
    return {
      classes: computed(() => ({
        'badge': true,
        'badge--highlighted': props.highlighted
      })),
      onClick() {
        emit('click');
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '_variables';

.badge {
  font-size: $badge-font-size;
  border-radius: $badge-border-radius;
  background-color: $badge-bg;
  color: $badge-color;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: $badge-line-height;
  padding: $badge-padding;
  
  &--highlighted {
    background-color: $badge-bg-accent;
    color: $badge-color-accent;
  }
}
</style>
```

I export component for npm package

```
// components/index.js

export { default as Badge }  from './Badge/Badge.vue';
```

Build npm package with Umd and Es files and publish as private package

In Nuxt project I installed package and created plugin to use it.

```
// plugins/CupPatternLibrary.ts

import Vue from 'vue';
import * as CupPatternLibrary from '@cambridgecore/cup-pattern-library';

Vue.use(CupPatternLibrary);

import {
  Badge
} from '@cambridgecore/cup-pattern-library'
Vue.component('Badge', Badge)
```

Registered plugin

```
// nuxt.config.js  

plugins: [
    '~/plugins/CupPatternLibrary.ts'
  ],
```

and want to use it

```
// landing-page.vue

<Badge label="xxx" />
```

And now i get TypeError and browser display error

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classes')`

in file

`node_modules\@cambridgecore\cup-pattern-library\dist\cup-pattern-library.umd.js:2:416`

So my question is how to make npm package to work with Nuxt project

Comment: I'm simply commenting as I do not have a solve for you at this time. I will point out that the error you are seeing is directly related to the Badge file. In other words, I think the error is rooted in _that_, not in the fact you are importing it into Nuxt.

I could be wrong, but I think your structure of your component might be missing a comma where there is a semi-colon instead.